# Apply conversion factor in a column for an aggregated table and perform calculation with another aggregated table

Tags: hive, data-conversion

I have the following tables in Hive. Is it possible to do all these operations by single query?
Following operations are done in tables:

In Table1, sum of users based on 'center' column
In Table2:

1. Each center code(A1) is associated with different accounts.
2. Conversion factor to be applied on Expense column (should be in Rupee)
3. Then find sum of expense

Output should be `Result=sum[Expense in Rupees]/sum[Users#]`

[image: Sample format of tables and expected output is provided as link below]

Any sort of guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been really easy to understand if you would have specified output values as well. To your question, Yes you can achieve conversion in one single query using CASE

```
SELECT
  center,
  account,
  SUM(expenses)/SUM(users) AS result
FROM
 (
  SELECT
    t2.center AS center,
    t1.users AS users,
    CASE
     WHEN t2.currency = 'USD' THEN (t2.expenses*70)
     WHEN t2.currency = 'MYR' THEN (t2.expenses*17)
     WHEN t2.currency = 'AUD' THEN (t2.expenses*50)
     WHEN t2.currency = 'INR' THEN t2.expenses
     ELSE 'invalid'
    END AS expenses,
    t2.currency AS currency,
    t2.account AS account
  FROM
  table1 t1 
  JOIN 
  table2 t2 
  ON(t1.center=t2.center)
 ) joined_data
GROUP BY center,account
ORDER BY center,account
```

I did not test this, but it should work. In worst case it might throw a minor syntax error, which you should be able to take care of it. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping.Would check and see the result. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please accept the answer if that resolves your issue. :)